# Replace value in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, replace

I like to replace a 'NULL' value in FG_NFG_Selektion column but only in those row where Plant='935S'

[image: current]

Tried:

UPDATE [Table] SET [FG_NFG_Selektion] = REPLACE([FG_NFG_Selektion], 'NULL', 'FG') WHERE [Plant] = '935S'

Message back: 10000 rows affected but still the same 'NULL' is there in the table.

Comment: ‘Null’ is not the same as null and you don’t need replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following query

```
UPDATE [Table] SET `FG_NFG_Selektion` = 'FG' WHERE `Plant` = '935S' AND `FG_NFG_Selektion` IS NULL;
```

Comment: IS NULL will use to check for the null values in SQL.

Comment: Also, do not forget to replace your actual table name with **[Table]**